# Permisos insuficientes en credencial de google calendar api

Tags: java, google-calendar, google-oauth

quisiera me pudieran ayudar estoy tratando de sincronizar una agenda en java con google calendar

actualmente estoy usando el client_secret por default que esta para quickstar en mi proyecto, muestra calendarios, eventos, pero cuando quiero insertar me sale error, y cuando trato de crear una nueva credencial con id oauth, resulta que no me sale ni siquiera la lista de calendarios disponibles

me podrian ayudar, les agradeceria

y una disculpa si no fui muy especifico, o el codigo que muestro es irrelevante

```
Caused by: com.google.api.client.googleapis.texto en negritajson.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden { 
"code" : 403, 
"errors" : [ { 
   "domain" : "global", 
   "message" : "Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.", 
   "reason" : "insufficientPermissions" } ], 
"message" : "Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes." }
```

el codigo que uso para la credencial en java es :

```
private static Credential getCredentials(final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT) throws IOException {

        // Load client secrets.
        InputStream in = CalendarG.class.getResourceAsStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
        if (in == null) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Resource not found: " + CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
        }
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

        // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                .setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(new java.io.File(TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH)))
                .setAccessType("offline")
                .build();
      
        Credential cred = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
        return cred;
    }
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0):

Para usar [Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/) no es suficiente habilitarla, también tienes que autorizar scopes. El problema se debe a que no has autorizado los "Scopes" que utilizaras:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> **Scopes**: son cadenas que permiten el acceso a recursos particulares,
>   como los datos del usuario. Usted incluye un alcance en ciertas
>   solicitudes de autorización, que luego muestra el texto de permisos
>   apropiado en un diálogo de consentimiento que se presenta a un
>   usuario. Una vez que el usuario acepta los permisos, Google envía sus
>   tokens de aplicación, que identifican la concesión de autorización
>   específica. En otras palabras, los ámbitos y los tokens determinan a
>   qué datos de usuario el usuario le da permiso a su aplicación para
>   acceder.

Comment: Hola que tal, te agradezco mucho 
Sabes, ya habilite los scopes de calendar y events

La verdad solo me sigue permitiendo la lectura desde la el client_secret que esta por default de quickstart

tambien creè un nuevo proyecto, eh hice la credencial con oauth de igual manera, tambien habilitando los scopes, pero en este caso, es donde no me permite ni leer los calendarios ni eventos

La verdad no se por donde ir para hayar el error que omiti
y de ante mano, gracias @Elenasys

Comment: Cual es el código que realizas , agregalo a tu pregunta.

Comment: Listo, espero sea a como tenias pensado, pero ese es mi codigo para usar la credencial

Comment: un ejemplo del error es cuando trato de modificar un everto que creè manualmente desde el calendario en google, y al querer actualizar al menos el titulo, es donde me sale el error pues, aun cuando si obtiene el evento por el id a actualizar, no realiza el update, marcando el error de permisos

Event updatedEvent = iniciarServicioCalendar().events().update(idCalendario, event.getId(), event).execute();